# SharePoint 2010 ListFeed.aspx not returning all items

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api

When I run a GET query like this:

```
http://website/sites/somesite/_layouts/listfeed.aspx?List=0f520f03-9d14-4019-9ced-c709aabe0ce6&View=b59d76a9-dec0-47b9-aecd-db0ff2899963
```

I get approximately 30 results back, but the list contains 370+ items.

How can I get ALL items back in 1 resultset? Or is there any support for a navigation url param?

Comment: We stay updated on changes to documents and list items on your SharePoint site by receiving notifications of changes through Really Simple Syndication (RSS). Why do you use it to get all items in the list?

Comment: Agree with @JoannaW_SPWX -- if you want all items in a list, you should use the List API. If you want updates, that's what the feed is good for, and you should refresh it regularly to stay up-to-date.

Comment: @JoannaW_SPWX I need to fetch all items in a list with all its fields. Unfortunately, SharePoint 2K ODATA REST API is a half-baked product, and they don't return custom fields values, so I have no other choice, but to use the older RSS feed API..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below configuration in List Settings --> RSS settings --> Item Limit

[image]

Comment: Seems to be working.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it solved your question